# Why laravel show route [setting.edit] not defined?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I have faced with this problem.Please tell me How to solve this.....
It show the messge like this :

**Route [setting.edit] not defined. (View: /home/rashed/Downloads/mahedy blog/resources/views/admin/layout/header.blade.php) (View: /home/rashed/Downloads/mahedy blog/resources/views/admin/layout/header.blade.php) (View: /home/rashed/Downloads/mahedy blog/resources/views/admin/layout/header.blade.php)**

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Settings;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\admin\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
         $users = admin::find(Auth::user()->id);
         return view('admin.settings.update',compact('users'));
    }
}
```

> Route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'] , function()
{

  Route::get('/backend','HomeController@ShowHomePage');

  Route::resource('backend/category','CategoryController');
  Route::resource('backend/tag','TagController');
  Route::resource('backend/post','PostController');
  Route::resource('backend/admin','AdminController');

  Route::resource('backend/settings','SettingsController');

  Route::resource('backend/profile','ProfileController');
  Route::resource('backend/youtube','YoutubeController');
  Route::resource('backend/email','EmailController');

  /****Admin Login Route*****/
  Route::get('backend/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
  Route::post('backend/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
  Route::post('backend/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must get the route name , try in the terminal this:

```
php artisan route:list
```

this will give you all the available routes with there names , you can get the name from there and use it

Answer (score 0):

Check your /admin/layout/header.blade.php file for a form that is trying to open to the route `setting.edit`.

Your routes file doesn't include a `settings` route, as you have posted it, and thus the form or route path from header.blade.php is calling to the wrong url.  Review and remove the setting.edit from the header form, or add the route/resource.

Comment: I think route name become `backend/settings.exit` not `settings.edit`.

Comment: Yep, possibly.  Either way, the fix is to edit either the blade file, or just add / edit the route within.

Answer (score 0):

Your route name become different if you add `backend` string . remove this word and add it in prefix

your routes should be like

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix'=>'backend'] , function()
 {
 Route::resource('settings','SettingsController');
 .....
  }
```

Now your route name `settings.edit` will work.
you can check your available routes by `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

- Remove "backend" and Your Route must be like this:

Route::resource('settings','SettingsController');

- And The function like that:

  public function edit(Settings $settings)
  {

  ```
  return view('admin.settings.edit',compact('settings'));
  ```

  }

"edit" not "update"